# How to pass the result of a python function to the html page where the action button was clicked (python bottle)

Tags: python, html, bottle

I have method:

```
@post('/home', method='post')
def myFunction():
    if(len(request.forms.get('Matrix_dimension').strip()) != 0):
    length = int(request.forms.get('Matrix_dimension').strip())
    tableRow = "<table>";
    for i in range(length):
        tableRow += "<tr>";
        for j in range(length):
            tableRow += "<td>";
            tableRow += "<input type=\"int\" max = \"1\" maxlength = \"1\"/>";
            tableRow += "</td>";
            tableRow += "</tr>";
            tableRow += "</table>"
    else:
        tableRow = "Enter value"
    return tableRow;
```

And when I click on the button, I need to draw a matrix of a certain dimension in order to receive user data from it in the future

```
<form action="/home" method="post"> <p><input class="text-field__input" type="int" name="Matrix_dimension" id="Matrix_dimension1" autofocus min = "2" max = "10" maxlength = "2"/> </p> <p>\<input type="submit" value="Send">\</p> <output name="result">\</output> </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not construct html strings inside a python function. The template engine can do this in a much cleaner way. But lets start with your code:

- remove the semicolons at the end of line, you don't need them in Python
- the code after `if` statement needs to be indented (4 spaces), the code as it is right now will not work

As to your actual problem, it could be entirely done within HTML with some javascript.

```
<button onclick="maketable()">Generate Table</button>
<input id="rows">

<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="mytablebody"></tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function maketable(){
        var rows = parseInt(document.querySelector("#rows").value);
        var tb = document.querySelector("#mytablebody");
        for (let step = 0; step < rows; step++) {
          var tr = document.createElement('tr');
          
          var td1 = document.createElement('td');
          var td2 = document.createElement('td');
          var td3 = document.createElement('td');

          var inp1 = document.createElement('input');
          var inp2 = document.createElement('input');
          var inp3 = document.createElement('input');

          td1.append(inp1);
          td2.append(inp2);
          td3.append(inp3);

          tr.append(td1);
          tr.append(td2);
          tr.append(td3);

          tb.append(tr);
        }
    }
</script>
```

We define a button that executes the function `maketable()`. The `maketable()` function gets the value from the `input` "rows" and runs a loop. It generates table rows (`tr`) and populates them with generated table data (`td`) elements, which again are populated with generated input elements. As to how you are going to gather all this and submit it to the server - well that is another problem ;-)